# KeyValuePattern specificity in DownValues

Tags: bugs, function-construction, pattern-matching, associations, downvalues

**Bug introduced in 10.4.0 and persisting through 11.3.0**

---

> CASE:3824590
>
> [...] Developers are discussing this behavior.  [...] I will let you know when  I have definite information on this. [...]

*Edit:* one year later, no followup feedback, issue persists

---

I was surprised to find out:

```
ClearAll[f, g];

f[KeyValuePattern[{_}]] := 1;
f[KeyValuePattern[{"test" -> _}]] := 2;

g[k[{_}]] := 1;
g[k[{"test" -> _}]] := 2;
```

```
DownValues@f
```

> ```
> {
>  HoldPattern[f[KeyValuePattern[{_}]]] :> 1, 
>  HoldPattern[f[KeyValuePattern[{"test" -> _}]]] :> 2
> }
> ```

```
DownValues@g
```

> ```
> {
>  HoldPattern[g[k[{"test" -> _}]]] :> 2, 
>  HoldPattern[g[k[{_}]]] :> 1
> }
> ```

that `KeyValuePattern[{_}]` is considered more specific than `KeyValuePattern[{"test" -> _}]`.

Which makes `f[<|"test" -> 1|>]` evaluate to `1` :(

#### The question

Is this expected?

#### Workaround notes

No, defining `f` in reverse order is not an option for me because the functionality is split between many independent packages.

No, manually prepending to `DownValues[f]` is not an option as I need automatic specificity for additional cases of `f`.

So the only solution I see is:

```
f[ass:KeyValuePattern[{}]]:=f[Lookup[ass, "test", "NA"], ass];
f["NA", _]:=1;
f[_, _]:=2;
```

or something. Not perfect but can live with this.

#### Further questions

Is there a better way to make `KeyValuePattern` to behave more consistently with the rest of the system?

Comment: I think this is worth reporting.  ``Internal`ComparePatterns[z[{"x" -> 1}], z[{_}]]`` yields `Specific` yet if we replace `z` with `KeyValuePattern` we get `Disjoint`.  Surely this is incorrect.

Comment: @WReach Do you agree to add bugs tag? It is still the case in 11.3 -.-

Comment: I am in two minds about it.  On the one hand, it sure feels like a bug to me.  On the other hand, pattern specificity is a complex subject and detailed analysis may reveal some underlying reason for this behaviour.  On balance, I suppose that adding the bugs tag may bring some welcome attention to the issue.  So, I agree.